# Problems with html form and hover effect of submit type button

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to warp/enclose HTML `<form>` element into a `<div>` element but it seems the border of the `<form>` goes beyond that of the `<div>`. Is there a way to fix it?

Also: the hover property effect not working on the **Submit type button** check the code snippet.

```css
body>.main-container {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid rgba(8, 5, 5, .5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 30%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 10px solid indianred;
  padding: 0%;
  marker: 0%;
  width: 100%;
}

form div button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 238, 237);
  background-color: rgb(255, 106, 69);
}

form>div>button[type=submit]:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 142, 120);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container'>
  <form>
    <div className="new-expense__controls">
      <div className="new-expense__control">
        <label> E-mail </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
      </div>

      <div className="pass__control">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit"> Login </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Your hover isn't working because you have two `div`s between `form` and `button`. This will work:
`form > div > div > button[type=submit]:hover`

Comment: still not working and I have tried 'button[type=submit]' and none of these works.

Comment: Maybe try Ctrl and F5 to refresh the page. Sometimes styles don't work because of caching.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what this means: "but it seems border of the goes beyond that of the . " I'm not certain I've understood which elements are involved here.

Comment: I have enclosed the tag name inside '<>' that's why 'div' and 'form' from the sentence you mentioned. Borders of the form element crossing div's enclosure and that is my problem.

Comment: I think a picture of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful. Currently main has a height set relative to the viewport dimension which means the login button may not be inside it visually - is it supposed to be? The too-wide problem is because you are picking up default margins etc. Setting box-sizing: border-box cures this but I haven't put an answer up because I'm still unclear what the final result in terms of the positioning of the inputs and button is to be.

Comment: Yes, set `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`. Also set both height and width for the form: `form { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to achieve in the first part of your question. But hover should work if you use correct selector. There are two `div`s between `form` and `button`. See the snippet:

```css
form>div>div>button[type=submit]:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 142, 120);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class='main-container'>
  <form>
    <div className="new-expense__controls">
      <div className="new-expense__control">
        <label> E-mail </label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" />
      </div>

      <div className="pass__control">
        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit"> Login </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 1st part of the question: I want the form element within div element have 100% of it's width and height but it is not working too? I have mentioned the tag name in the question those disappeared from the question and I can't edit my question anymore.

Comment: Also it seems hover effect not working on Responsive design mode.

Comment: just check out the style in responsive mode you will know.

Comment: Responsive mode works like a mobile which doesn't have hover. You can't hover anything on smartphone or tablet, you can only touch it